# Understanding the log taking limitation in limits of form $0^0$ and $\infty^0$

Tags: limits

Suppose we want to evaluate $\lim _{x \rightarrow a}(f(x))^{g(x)}$ of form $0^0$ or $\infty^0$
The steps would be like this:

> Let $L=\lim _{x \rightarrow a}(f(x))^{g(x)}$. Then,
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \log _{e} L &=\log _{e}\left[\lim _{x \rightarrow a}\{f(x)\}^{g(x)}\right] \\
> &=\lim _{x \rightarrow a}\left[\log _{e}\{f(x)\}^{g(x)}\right] \\
> &=\lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x) \log _{e}[f(x)] \\
> L &=\lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x) \log _{e} f(x)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> My query is are we from starting **assuming L exists** and therefore taking log of the limit as such limit will come outside of log only if we are guaranteed to have that **log is continuous at x= L** .

Comment: If $L$ exists, then you can evaluate it by this method. Once you have the alleged limit $L$, you can check to see whether it is consistent with the basic facts about the logarithm and the other functions involved.

Comment: Okay you mean if L comes out to be -1/2 or say -infinity in that case we will say limit doesnt exist because log is not continuous at those points ? Or we will say its exist at - infinity when x is close to zero ?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from just writing $\exp[\log(\lim_{x\to a}(f(x))^{g(x)})]$ all the way through (so keeping $\exp(\log(\dots))$. This also makes it clearer that you need to check you can actually move limit (need function to be continious there). You are correct that when you write $L=\lim_{x\to a}(f(x))^{g(x)}$ you are assuming limit exists.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough that $L$ exists.  Take for example $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=x^2$.  Then
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x))^{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}0^{x^2} = 0\tag 1$$
The last line of your derivation reads however
$$\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) \ln f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0}x^2 \ln 0\tag 2$$
which does not exists.

There are two problems with:$\def\pow{\operatorname{pow}}$

$$\begin{align}
\pow:(\Bbb R_0^+\times\Bbb R_0^+)\setminus{(0,0)} &\to \Bbb R \\
(x,y)\qquad&\mapsto x^y
\end{align}$$

First, $\pow$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ and that mixed badly with limits at that point.  For example, when you approach the origin by the line $x=y$, then you get a limit of 1.  But when you approach the origin by the $y$-axis $x=0$, then the limit is 0. To whichever value you are going to define $\pow(0,0)$, it won't fix that.

Second, $\pow$ does not handle negative arguments, which requires additional constraints on $f$ and $g$, i.e. $(f(x),g(x))$ should remain in the 1st quadrant as $x\to 0$. In most cases, you'll have to restrict to a one-sided limit.